# Apply a function within another, using the same list in R

Tags: r, list, function, lapply

I need help, I'm tryin to run a function within another function with the same df but an error message always appears when I run the code

Here's below a sample of my df

```
X <- c("Bloc", "Mp", "xcible",  "ycible", "xO", "yO", "xN", "yN", "xE", "yE", "xS", "yS", "ID_ligne")
C <- c("LE-01", 22, 2.404024, -39.5192, -7.296761, -43.66444, -8.135254, -0.8619174, 6.710631, 0.20917, 7.339786, -41.44318, "LE-01-B-006-22")
D <- c("LE-01", 20, 1.362262, -40.59871, -7.296761, -43.66444, -8.135254, -0.8619174, 6.710631, 0.20917, 7.339786, -41.44318, "LE-01-B-006-20")
E <-c("LE-01", 22, 2.404024, -39.5192, -7.296761, -43.66444, -8.135254, -0.8619174, 6.710631, 0.20917, 7.339786, -41.44318, "LE-01-B-005-22")
G <- c("LE-01", 20, 1.362262, -40.59871, -7.296761, -43.66444, -8.135254, -0.8619174, 6.710631, 0.20917, 7.339786, -41.44318, "LE-01-B-005-20")
H <- c("LE-01", 24, 1.710175, -33.79383, -7.296761, -43.66444, -8.135254, -0.8619174, 6.710631, 0.20917, 7.339786, -41.44318, "LE-01-B-004-24") 
J <- c("LE-01", 22, 2.404024, -39.5192, -7.296761, -43.66444, -8.135254, -0.8619174, 6.710631, 0.20917, 7.339786, -41.44318, "LE-01-B-003-22")

Ex <- rbind(C,D,E,G,H,J)
colnames(Ex) <- X
Ex <- as.data.frame(Ex)
Ex$xO <- as.numeric(as.character(Ex$xO))
Ex$xS <- as.numeric(as.character(Ex$xS))
Ex$xN <- as.numeric(as.character(Ex$xN))
Ex$xE <- as.numeric(as.character(Ex$xE))
Ex$yO <- as.numeric(as.character(Ex$yO))
Ex$yS <- as.numeric(as.character(Ex$yS))
Ex$yN <- as.numeric(as.character(Ex$yN))
Ex$yE <- as.numeric(as.character(Ex$yE))
Ex.list <- split(Ex, f = Ex$ID_ligne)
```

Here's next the function which is in the bigger I try to run

```
eq_affine <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2){
  pente <- (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)
  int <- y2 - pente*x2
  return(c(pente, int))
```

The bigger function but reduced to the line when the error message occurs

```
 exp_lin_fun_rect <- function(xO, xS, xE, xN, 
                             yO, yS, yE, yN,
                             xcible, ycible,
                             xcompe, ycompe){

  eqSE <- eq_affin(xS, yS, xE, yE)
  eqEN <- eq_affine(xE, yE, xN, yN)
  eqNO <- eq_affine(xN, yN, xO, yO)
  eqOS <- eq_affine(xO, yO, xS, yS)
  return(data.frame(cbind(eqSE, eqEN, eqNO, eqOS)))
}
```

And the code I tried to run :

```
Ex <- unlist(lapply(Ex.list, exp_lin_fun_rect))
```

Error message is always  `Error in eq_affine(xS, yS, xE, yE) : 
  argument "yE" is missing, with no default`

No need to have the rest of the bigger function because the error occurs in the first row of the code. And I'm using a list because I have a tons of data and it's easier for me to work that way

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried `Ex <- unlist(lapply(Ex.list, with, exp_lin_fun_rect(xO, xS, xE, xN, 
                                                    yO, yS, yE, yN,
                                                    xcible, ycible,
                                                    xcompe, ycompe)))` ?

Comment: Thanks you, it worked without the unlist

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly amended your code:

```
# Set up original dataframe like so: 

Ex <- setNames(data.frame(rbind(C,D,E,G,H,J), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), X)

# Clean data: 

Ex <- data.frame(lapply(Ex,
       function(x) {
         if(suppressWarnings(sum(is.na(as.numeric(x)))) == sum(is.na(x))){
           x <- as.numeric(x)
         } else{
           as.character(x)
         }
       }))

# Define function:
eq_affine <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2){
  pente <- (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)
  int <- y2 - pente*x2
  return(c(pente, int))
}


# Define function: 
exp_lin_fun_rect <- function(xO, xS, xE, xN, yO, yS, yE, yN, xcible, ycible,
                             xcompe, ycompe){
  eqSE <- eq_affine(xS, yS, xE, yE)
  eqEN <- eq_affine(xE, yE, xN, yN)
  eqNO <- eq_affine(xN, yN, xO, yO)
  eqOS <- eq_affine(xO, yO, xS, yS)

  return(list(eqSE = eqSE, eqEN = eqEN, eqNO = eqNO, eqOS = eqOS))

}

# Apply function: 
exp_lin_fun_rect(Ex$xO, Ex$xS, Ex$xE, Ex$xN, Ex$yO, Ex$yS, Ex$yE, Ex$yN, 
                 Ex$xcible, Ex$ycible, Ex$xcompe, Ex$ycompe)
```

Data:

```
X <- c("Bloc", "Mp", "xcible",  "ycible", "xO", "yO", "xN", "yN", "xE", "yE", "xS", "yS", "ID_ligne")
C <- c("LE-01", 22, 2.404024, -39.5192, -7.296761, -43.66444, -8.135254, -0.8619174, 6.710631, 0.20917, 7.339786, -41.44318, "LE-01-B-006-22")
D <- c("LE-01", 20, 1.362262, -40.59871, -7.296761, -43.66444, -8.135254, -0.8619174, 6.710631, 0.20917, 7.339786, -41.44318, "LE-01-B-006-20")
E <-c("LE-01", 22, 2.404024, -39.5192, -7.296761, -43.66444, -8.135254, -0.8619174, 6.710631, 0.20917, 7.339786, -41.44318, "LE-01-B-005-22")
G <- c("LE-01", 20, 1.362262, -40.59871, -7.296761, -43.66444, -8.135254, -0.8619174, 6.710631, 0.20917, 7.339786, -41.44318, "LE-01-B-005-20")
H <- c("LE-01", 24, 1.710175, -33.79383, -7.296761, -43.66444, -8.135254, -0.8619174, 6.710631, 0.20917, 7.339786, -41.44318, "LE-01-B-004-24") 
J <- c("LE-01", 22, 2.404024, -39.5192, -7.296761, -43.66444, -8.135254, -0.8619174, 6.710631, 0.20917, 7.339786, -41.44318, "LE-01-B-003-22")
```

Comment: can you explain why the original approach results in the error  message "Error in eq_affine(xS, yS, xE, yE) : argument "yE" is missing, with no default?"

Comment: @sachin2014 firstly you haven't defined the eq_affine function it is missing a closing "}". Secondly the data-types in your dataframe are not correct so arithmetic operations won't work as they are factors/strings. Thirdly you are not applying the function correctly as you are not providing arguments to the parameters of the function. If you have found this solution useful please upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: Fourth you haven't defined the object to be returned in your  exp_lin_fun_rect function.

Comment: @sachin2014 no worries, please accept my solution if it does what you require.

Comment: @sachin2014 As I said, I do not know why the first approach results in this error message. I have all my values in numeric at the beginning so arithmetic operations might work.

Comment: @hello_friend Thanks for the answer, but I'm really trying to work in a list. Is there a way where I just provide arguments in my ```exp_lin_fun_rect```  and let the ```eq_affine``` use the same arguments ?

Comment: @AlexisBegni edited solution now returns a list object as required.